# Defining directory as the variable

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have simple question regarding defining the variables for the folder and make some operations with this

for my example I define workdir as the dirr at the beginning of my script 
than I make some looping within the some subdirs of the $dirr and at the end of each looping I need to return to the ./${dir} which is equal to the double cd ( cd .. cd .. )

```
#!/bin/bash
receptors= ./Receptors
dirr= /home/gleb/Documents/script
echo ${dirr}
#looping of the each pdb file in the Receptors folder
for pdb in $receptors/*.pdb; do
  # some sequence of commands
  cd $dirr
  #cd ..
  #cd ..
done
```

the problem is that the cd .. cd .. method works fine but  cd $dirr is not worked . 1) What should be fixed here ?  2) How to obtain path for the $dirr ( echo ${dirr} is also not works ) ?

Thanks for help,

James

Comment: Are the spaces in the variable assignments in your actual code?

Comment: @user000001 This is likely the problem. @JamesStarlight the fact that `echo ${dirr}` does not work should alert you that it has not been set.

Comment: You aren't assigning a value to `dirr`; you're running `/home/gleb/Documents/script` with an empty value of `dirr` in its environment.

Comment: Add set -o nounset to your script, so it will terminate if you reference an unset variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pushd` and `popd`:

```
pushd /tmp         # Go to /tmp, but remember where we were
...
do something
...
popd               # Return wherever we were
```

Comment: xz = /tmp; cd $xz; do something; popd                            will it   also work?